# Go to detail view of an article list with React-Native

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

I'm trying to create list of articles. Currently, I have the first view that show all articles on a list view. And when we click on an article, we must be redirecting on an other view that show the details of this article. But I don't know the way how to get details of articles.

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView, TouchableHighlight, 
ActivityIndicator, Image } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Article from './article';

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isLoading: true
  }
}

static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Articles'
}

componentDidMount() {
  return fetch('http://www.femininbio.com/json/liste-articles')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

renderRow(rowData) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight id={rowData.id} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Article')} underlayColor='#F5FCFF' style={styles.item}>
    <View style={styles.itemView}>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: rowData.i.u}}/>
      <View style={styles.blockText}>
        <Text style={styles.titleArticle}>{rowData.t}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.rubrique}>Rubrique : {rowData.r.n}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loading}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          style={styles.list}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

So I lunch an other view with the stacknavigator, I think that I must use props to get id of the articles and to filter data but is a little blurry for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While navigating to a new screen you can pass parameters to the new screen. With the parameter you get in the new screen you can make a new fetch or just use the information you passed to show data on screen. You can read more about on this topic at [react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#navigate-Link-to-other-screens)

**Example**

```
<TouchableHighlight 
  id={rowData.id} 
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Article', { article: rowData})}>
  // ...
</TouchableHighlight>

// And in your Article Screen
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.article) // will print article object/data
```

Comment: Ok thank, I for the article screen, I must to get results with an other link that contain more information about articles. So I need to use a fetch again to get only one result. It is possible to create a fetch for one result ?

Comment: @Guillaume thats really much related to your API